# Sprite Methods in Sprite Groups Pygame

Tags: python, methods, pygame, init

I'm having a little trouble and I was wondering if you could help me fix it.

So I've made a sprite and created an idle animation method which I'm calling in the `__init__` method like so.

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.attributes = "blah"

        self.idleAnimation()

    def idleAnimation(self):
        self.animationCode = "Works normally I've checked it"

player      = Player()
playerGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
playerGroup.add(player)
window = pygame.display.set_mode(yaddi-yadda)

while StillLooping:
    window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    playerGroup.update()
    playerGroup.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

But for whatever reason the idleAnimation method isn't being run within the group despite being called in the `__init__` method. If I call it later on in the loop:

```
while StillLooping:
    player.idleAimation()
    window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    playerGroup.update()
    playerGroup.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

It runs but not otherwise. I can't work out why. Any ideas would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `idleAnimation()` method is not magically called by the `playerGroup.update()` method.  I don't really understand why you think it should be...

The documentation of [`Group.update`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update)  says that this calls the `update()` method of every sprite, so you should rename the method to `update()` if you want it to be called every loop.

Comment: I didn't think it should be magically anything, rather because the idleAnimation method was called in the instantiation method which would ordinarily have run it automatically. But thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `__init__` method is called only once, when you instanciate your object. So your `idleAnimation()` method is called when you create your object, and that's it.

Your group's `update()` method will only call your sprite's `update` method, so you need to either rename `idleAnimation()`, as has been suggested, or add an `update()` method that calls it, which should prove more flexible:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.attributes = "blah"

        self.idleAnimation() # You can probably get rid of this line

    def idleAnimation(self):
        self.animationCode = "Works normally I've checked it"

    def update(self):
        '''Will be called on each iteration of the main loop'''
        self.idleAnimation()
```

Chances are you don't need to call `idleAnimation()` in your initializer, since it will run afterwards within your loop.